# Convert recorded audio into mp3 programmatically?

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I need to convert any recorded audio file to mp3 in java server side. Please help me on this regard I am very much struck on this from long time. If anyone knows the solution please let me know. Your help is highly appreciated.

Teja.

Comment: It would help if you told the source format, not just the target format.

Comment: We are using the source format as *.amr and we want to convert it to *.mp3

Comment: I am saving file as .raw now want to convert .raw to mp3 please help me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com) should do the trick here - it'll let you convert all types of audio from one format to another, not just mp3, and is cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a solution which is not cross platform, you can try [LAME](http://lame.sourceforge.net/index.php).

```
Runtime.exec("lame ...");
```